# How to make a random unique number only used once

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a program that makes a random code list and translates the text to the code. I'm having trouble figuring out how to make it so that the code is equal to a single random letter in a list.

This is the code I have so far :

```
loop = 0
while loop < 24:
    numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
    letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    random.shuffle(numbers)
    random.shuffle(letters)
    print(numbers, "=", letters)
    loop = loop + 1
    if loop == 24:
        print("test")
```

It's outputting something like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

It should, in theory, look something like this when it's outputted:
1 = g, 2 = w, 3 = k, and so on.

Comment: This isn't at all clear. Your code doesn't even attempt to use the `random` module. Maybe you could look into thinks like `random.shuffle` and `random.sample`.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that I was trying something else with the code and forgot to change that back. I'll change that now

Comment: store the random number generated in a set and check for the new random number. If you are able to add new random number in the set, then it is not used, else it is already assigned.

Comment: You just need the ```letters``` and then ```shufle()``` it. You will have a random index/letter association already.

Comment: okay thanks Vishal I'll implement those. Do you know how to select one random number and letter for it?

Comment: Just noticed you are doing ```loop=0``` and ```while loop < 24:``` which will count from 0 to 23, and it looks like it is not what you want. You better replace that (and delete the associated ```loop = loop + 1``` bit) with ```for loop in range(26):```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary lookup for shuffled values to and from lower ascii using the `string` module and `random` - `enumerate` gives you indexes into the shuffled string:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
import random
atoz = list(ascii_lowercase)
random.shuffle(atoz)

# add the index:character translation    
d = { idx:char for idx,char in enumerate(atoz) }

# update with the reverse translation:
d.update( {c:k for k,c in d.items() } )
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{0: 'w', 1: 'e', 2: 'v', 3: 'r', 4: 'm', 5: 'n', 6: 'z', 7: 'x', 8: 'g', 
 9: 'j', 10: 'p', 11: 'y', 12: 'q', 13: 'c', 14: 'u', 15: 'a', 16: 't', 
17: 'l', 18: 'f', 19: 's', 20: 'h', 21: 'i', 22: 'b', 23: 'o', 24: 'k', 
25: 'd', 
'w': 0, 'e': 1, 'v': 2, 'r': 3, 'm': 4, 'n': 5, 'z': 6, 'x': 7, 'g': 8, 
'j': 9, 'p': 10, 'y': 11, 'q': 12, 'c': 13, 'u': 14, 'a': 15, 't': 16, 
'l': 17, 'f': 18, 's': 19, 'h': 20, 'i': 21, 'b': 22, 'o': 23, 'k': 24, 'd': 25}
```

To translate using this dictionary:

```
def word_to_ints(word, d):
    return [d.get(c,c) for c in word.lower()]

def ints_to_word(ints, d):
    return ''.join( (d.get(n,n) for n in ints) )

k = word_to_ints("Translate me", d )

print(k, "=", ints_to_word(k, d))
```

Output:

```
[16, 3, 15, 5, 19, 17, 15, 16, 1, ' ', 4, 1] = translate me
```

Doku:

- [enumerate(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
- [random.shuffle(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)
- [string.ascii_lowercase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase)
- [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)

Comment: This ```d = { idx:char for idx,char in enumerate(atoz) }``` can be simplified by ```d = dict(enumerate(atoz))``` which is clearer IMHO.

Comment: @accdias valid, but I prefer the dict comprehension, thanks for commenting

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example of what I said in my comment:

```
from random import shuffle
from string import ascii_lowercase

letters = list(ascii_lowercase)
shuffle(letters)

list(enumerate(letters))
```

The output of the above code is something like this:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(list(enumerate(letters)))
[(0, 'z'),
 (1, 'a'),
 (2, 's'),
 (3, 'y'),
 (4, 'o'),
 (5, 'h'),
 (6, 'p'),
 (7, 'v'),
 (8, 'l'),
 (9, 'r'),
 (10, 'e'),
 (11, 'i'),
 (12, 'm'),
 (13, 'g'),
 (14, 'b'),
 (15, 'q'),
 (16, 'n'),
 (17, 'u'),
 (18, 'd'),
 (19, 'k'),
 (20, 'x'),
 (21, 'c'),
 (22, 'j'),
 (23, 't'),
 (24, 'f'),
 (25, 'w')]
>>>
```